# Creating a Sequelize Dialect for new Database

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm pretty new to sequelize, though I've worked on node previously I did not use any ORM framework. At present I'm using new SQL DB(which is not supported by sequelize ) and want to connect it using node.js and sequelize( popular ORM for node.js ) by prototyping the existing dialects

The configuration is correct as I've tried it wihtout ORM.
The problem is after configuring the connection with properties the 
    sequelize.authenticate() doesn't throw any error but doesn't return a promise back

```
 /**
   * Test the connection by trying to authenticate
   *
   * @error 'Invalid credentials' if the authentication failed (even if the database did not respond at all...)
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  authenticate(options) {
    return this.query('SELECT 1+1 AS result', _.assign({ raw: true, plain: true }, options)).return();
  }
```

The return statement doesn't return anything. I've read this post [how to create a new dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395933/how-to-create-a-new-sequelize-dialect-for-example-db2). Though it says it is not encouraged to create a new dialect and throws an error if we try to, I think there must be a way to create because if it can be created for other SQL databases then may be there should be a way to do it. [This is an open source project on github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize). Did anyone previously work on this any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Only the 5 dialects are supported and an error will be thrown if you try and use NewSQL.

There is a lot of code in Sequelize to construct queries based on the dialect, so even if you could get past the error (such as forking the repo and changing it) the likelihood of everything working as you expect (or as is documented) is low.

I suggest posting an issue on GitHub to bring that dialect to the project.